# Why Software Recommendations SE least answered?

Tags: discussion

I've been discovering  **Software Recommendations Stack Exchange** and although I kind of like the topic, my impression is that this SE is not doing great

Apparently there's just not enough regular active members for the flow of questions ([48% answered](https://stackexchange.com/sites#technology-traffic)). Crucially there are very few votes being cast, and this is quite bad given that the SE model relies on votes.

My question is that why **Software Recommendations SE** least answered site?

Comment: Welcome Pluviophile! Does the following Meta QA help you? https://softwarerecs.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/636/is-the-proportion-of-unanswered-questions-a-concern

Comment: Pluviophile, is there anything in your question that is not covered by https://softwarerecs.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/636/is-the-proportion-of-unanswered-questions-a-concern ? The number of members and votes is worth discussing but sounds more like an answer than a part of this question. Thanks :-)

Comment: [@RockPaperLizard's answer is pretty good](https://softwarerecs.meta.stackexchange.com/a/2916/67937)

Comment: If I may add to RockPaperLizard's answer linked above, it's not just some requests are too specific that the software may not currently exist, but some requests are simply too vague: "I need to do <task>" without any context for OS, cost, library or app, etc.

Answer (score 4):

In my limited experience, this is at least to some extent due to an extremely negative attitude on the part of high-reputation StackOverflow users.

On StackOverflow, it's a big no-no to ask for recommendations for some library or app to solve a problem you have. That gets your question closed and likely downvoted; on a good day, you get directed to go here and ask. But there's still a sense that questions requesting software recommendations are somehow base and dirty and inappropriate. Maybe for this reason and maybe for others - high-reputation SO users don't come here on the site to try and answer questions relevant to their field of expertise. Even I, who have asked quite a lot here, have mostly answered my own questions - and I'm all for SR.SE

Comment: Thanks for your post.  I wasn't aware of this, and I find it a bit funny (and sad) that anyone would ever feel like it was "base and dirty" to ask for a software recommendation.  Then again, I'm a lizard, so I thrive in "base and dirty". ;)

Comment: @RockPaperLz-MaskitorCasket: Perhaps you should consider opening a discussion about this on meta.stackexchange.com . I don't know how much good that will do, but maybe _some_. After all, programmers tend to like Lizards.