# We need more activity

Tags: discussion

I checked the [site statistics](https://stackexchange.com/sites?view=list#percentanswered) and [Software Recommendations](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/)  has the least percent of answered questions of all the sites. 49 percent. Is there anything we can do to get more activity?

Comment: Welcome – and thanks for your concern! We dealt with this topic here recently, less than 2 months ago, see: [Why Software Recommendations SE least answered?](https://softwarerecs.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2908/185)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Welcome to Software Recommendations SE, "96 94".  I happen to be friends with your [aunt, 99](https://invidio.us/watch?v=I6UQW64hxMI).

Our community is a bit different from other SE communities in that there is a much greater chance of there being no possible answer to some of our questions.

For example, if someone asks for the impossible, like a completely gratis (free of financial cost) operating system that is both reliable and completely open-source, there are obviously no possible answers.  Oh, wait... Linux.  Bad example. ;)

Being serious though, many of our questions will intentionally remain unanswered until there are software products that match the requester's specifications.  Those unanswered questions are by design.

I think it would be interesting to know how many of our unanswered questions are currently answerable, and I welcome any way to determine *that* metric!